# Persist Tooltip long enough to click a link in Google Calendar Chart

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-visualization

I'm trying to set-up a Google Calendar chart so that when the user clicks on a date a tooltip displays containing custom HTML, including a link. I want the tooltip to persist so the user can actually click on the link in the tooltip. I've tried adding `tooltip: {trigger: 'selection'}` but it doesn't do anything. Does anyone know how to get the tooltip to persist? Thanks!

```
<script type="text/javascript" id="capture-dates-calendar">
  google.charts.load("current", {packages:["calendar"]});
  google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

 function drawChart() {
     var dataTable = new google.visualization.DataTable();
     dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'date', id: 'Date' });
     dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'number', id: 'Captures' });
     dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'string', role: 'tooltip', p: {'html': true} });
     dataTable.addRows([
        [ new Date(2016,6,10),2,'<div class="calendar-tooltip"><h5>July 10, 2016</h5><p>2 snapshots</p><ul><li><a href="http://wayback.archive-it.org/3507/20160710175703/https://twitter.com/HTI_HTIC/" target="_blank">17:57:03</a></li><li><a href="http://wayback.archive-it.org/3507/20160710135341/https://twitter.com/HTI_HTIC/" target="_blank">13:53:41</a></li></ul></div>']
      ]);

     var chart = new google.visualization.Calendar(document.getElementById('calendar_basic'));

     var options = { 
        focusTarget: 'category',
        tooltip: { 
          isHtml: true,
          trigger: 'selection'
         },
        colorAxis: { minValue: 1,  colors: ['#17649a', '#0b2e47'] } 
     };                     

     chart.draw(dataTable, options);

 }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

must be why `trigger: 'selection'` is missing from the [config options](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/calendar#configuration-options)

you could use the `'select'` event to show the same tooltip in a separate `div`

see following working example...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: function () {
    var dataTable = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'date', id: 'Date' });
    dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'number', id: 'Captures' });
    dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'string', role: 'tooltip', p: {'html': true} });
    dataTable.addRows([
      [ new Date(2016,6,10),2,'<div class="calendar-tooltip"><h5>July 10, 2016</h5><p>2 snapshots</p><ul><li><a href="http://wayback.archive-it.org/3507/20160710175703/https://twitter.com/HTI_HTIC/" target="_blank">17:57:03</a></li><li><a href="http://wayback.archive-it.org/3507/20160710135341/https://twitter.com/HTI_HTIC/" target="_blank">13:53:41</a></li></ul></div>']
    ]);

    var options = {
      focusTarget: 'category',
      tooltip: {
        isHtml: true
      },
      colorAxis: { minValue: 1,  colors: ['#17649a', '#0b2e47'] }
    };

    var chart = new google.visualization.Calendar(document.getElementById('calendar_basic'));
    var tooltip = document.getElementById('calendar_tooltip');
    google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'select', function() {
      var selection = chart.getSelection();
      if ((selection.length > 0) && (selection[0].hasOwnProperty('row'))) {
        tooltip.innerHTML = dataTable.getValue(selection[0].row, 2);
      } else {
        tooltip.innerHTML = '';
      }
    });

    chart.draw(dataTable, options);
  },
  packages: ['corechart', 'calendar']
});
```

```css
#calendar_tooltip {
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  border: 1px solid #E0E0E0;
  height: 156px;
  width: 128px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="calendar_basic"></div>
<div id="calendar_tooltip"></div>
```

Comment: thought about using the `getBoundingBox` [method](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/calendar#methods) to move the tooltip `div` -- but doesn't work properly, directly or with`getChartLayoutInterface`

Comment: trigger: 'selection' is part of the tooltip configuration options. The documentation says "Tooltips can trigger on focus as well as selection. However, with tooltip actions, selection is preferable. That causes the tooltip to persist, allowing the user to select the action more easily." See [link](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/customizing_tooltip_content#tooltip-actions)

Comment: i'm aware, but that option is specifically not listed on the config options for Calendar chart, where it is on others, such as Line chart. using that option on a Line chart works fine...